# android starting foreground service with START_STICKY

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, background-service, foreground-service

I could not understand new features of android about services.In google documentation, after `oreo` developers must use foreground service to start service  when application is on background.

I found this descriptions.

'Starting from Android O, if your application is in the background (check above three conditions), your application is allowed to create and run background services for some minutes.

After some minutes passed, your application will enter in the idle stage. When your application enteres in the idle stage, the system will stop all the background services just like your service calls `Service.stopSelf()`.'

I could not understand that even if I start service with START_STICKY, will it not start again ? I know like that if I start with  START_STICKY ,it will exactly restart after kill.Why I must use `JobScheduler` for some needs (location updates etc.).Can someone explain it.I could not understand google documents very well.

I test it now on `galaxy note 8 api26` phone.I started service with startService when app starts  and it restarted after close app.What is the differences between older versions

Thank you.

Comment: The main reason is battery life. In older versions of Android, developers exploited this exact issue keeping their apps running non stop on the device and never gets killed, thus draining battery life of the device. Reason for having to start a foreground service is so the user is aware of your app running and can kill it anytime the user wants.

Comment: I got it but what happen if I used startservice from activity? I saw that it started again after app close.I could not see any problem of programatically

Comment: If it is a foreground service, it is fine to run just like the olden days. As long as in your service, you call `Service.Startforground(new notification...` else the service will just stop again and maybe crash the app. I think you have like 5 seconds to make that call

Comment: I have started service by startservice when app starts but nothing happened.İf I start it from background yes it will throw error.

Comment: Well, I would like to see all the relevant code to be able to help you. Service code, the section where you start the service, etc.

Comment: I added it below.ı have not started foreground.

Comment: I don't see you adding an Action when you start the service, yet you call `intent.getAction()` in StartCommand. Try adding an action `serviceIntent.setAction("some.action");`

Comment: I did.İt will continue to run .when app closed . it restarts

Comment: By using START_STICKY flag, will the service be restarted in case of phone reboot ??

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {

    private Intent serviceIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("name", "ahmet vefa saruhan");
        startService(serviceIntent);
        findViewById(R.id.textview).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```java
    public class MyService extends Service {

    private String myaction;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("MYSERVICE STATUS: "," ONSTARTCOMMAND action : " + ((intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("name") != null) ? intent.getStringExtra("name") : "yok") + " OLD ACTION : "+(myaction != null ? myaction : "yok"));
        Log.d("MYTHREAD name : ",Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //intent.putExtra("name","isim değişti");
        myaction = (intent != null) ? intent.getAction() : null;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       Log.d("MYSERVICE STATUS: "," ONCREATED");
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground()
    {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("MYSERVICE STATUS: "," ONDESTROYED");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.d("MYSERVICE STATUS: "," onTaskRemoved");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
```